# Customize laravel Http errors

Tags: php, laravel, api, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

In API application I want to customize http errors (like 404, 500 or other http errors)
I want to respond in this format

```
return response()->json(['message' => '', 'data' => null, 'result' => false],[specific error code]);
```

instead of showing laravel default error page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IWzE.png)

how can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `404.blade.php` in this `/resources/views/errors/` folder. 
You can write whatever html you choose in this file to display to your users, and now when you get the 404 error this page will show to you 
**For other error pages** 
For example for 500 error page just create this file `500.blade.php`, that it

Answer (score -1):

enter this command, and the views of errors will be available to edit, in the views file.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```